# Tk Canvas appearing with nothing on them when canvas.create_window is used

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter, window

I'm making a game with buttons being placed onto my main canvas. However, every one of these buttons, whenever they are drawn, are creating another, smaller, blank canvas. They keep going in front of the game and are extremely annoying.

Does anyone know how I can have these buttons on my canvas, but not have these other windows (I think they may be the default windows that the buttons would normally be drawn on) appearing? Also, these windows, when closed, cause errors (below).

I'm not exactly sure what is causing it, and my code is over 1500 lines long - So I haven't put any in (apart from the code for one of my buttons)

```
btncont = Button(text = "Continue", command = Continue, anchor = W)
btncont.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5")
btncont_window =  canvas.create_window(300, 600, anchor=NW, window=btncont)
```

```
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/idlelib/run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

>>>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/Admin/Desktop/NewPomg/Pong - Revolutions [Version 6.0.1].py", line 1179, in TwoPlayer
    tk.update_idletasks()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 970, in update_idletasks
    self.tk.call('update', 'idletasks')
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command:  application has been destroyed
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explicitly declare the parent of your buttons as its first parameter.

Comment: How exactly? (Sorry, i've not been doing python for that long)

Comment: As in, `btncont = Button(the_window_containing_this_button, text = "Continue", command = Continue, anchor = W)`

Comment: Still does nothing unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `create_window`, the button should be a child of the canvas. For example:

```
btncont = Button(canvas, text = "Continue", command = Continue, anchor = W)
```

I doubt that's what's causing the stack traces, but it might be part of the problem. Since you are using queues, my guess is that you're using threading, and tkinter isn't thread safe. So, if you are using threading, and you are trying to draw on the canvas from more than one thread, that's definitely part of the problem.

If you're writing something simple like a pong game, you don't need threads at all. So the first step might be to remove the threads and use `after` to do your animation. There are several examples on this website for how to do that.